# If range contains value then return contents of another cell in same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a recording doc where I input a value of "1" when recording a specific item. In another colum on the same row I then record certain notes related to that item. 
Because there is a large amount of colums I'm recording, it is not efficient for me to continually filter each colum to collect the relevant notes each time.

I have created another colum where I want to return each of the notes specific to that item.

Please see below example:

[image]

I believe a rough formula of what I'm looking for should be:

***"Notes for Item 1"***

For ranges: `A2:A100`

```
IF A(x) = 1 then return C(x)
```

&

***"Notes for Item 2"***

For ranges: `B2:B100`

```
 IF B(x) = 1 then return C(x)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following array formulas.
(1) Formula in `D2` cell

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$100,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$100<>"",ROW($A$2:$A$100)-ROW($A$1),""),ROWS($A$2:$A2))),"")
```

(2) Formula in `E2` cell

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$100,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$100<>"",ROW($A$2:$A$100)-ROW($A$1),""),ROWS($A$2:$A2))),"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

Comment: Again you must have to press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` after entering formula to cells.

Comment: Thanks harun24hr - I'm not sure I fully understand the formula but I've been successfully able to adapt this to my master document. Thank you

Comment: sorry, can you please advise how I could modify this formula to count only those results in a select range.

e.g 

1.) range A5:A10
2.) ranges A2:A5 & A7:A10


Thanks

Comment: Change ranges everywhere in formula as `A5:A10` or `A2:A5`